# Merge [amazon-bedrock] and [bedrock]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

The tags [amazon-bedrock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-bedrock) and [bedrock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bedrock) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Comment: There are three questions tagged bedrock, and two of them already have the amazon-bedrock tag as well. Given the tag guidance, I don't see a reason why an individual (such as yourself) can't just handle this unilaterally. Making a tag synonym etc. is a bigger step, and requires some evidence that the *future* site will benefit (e.g. likelihood that many future users will continue splitting the tag).

Comment: [The one that's not already tagged \[amazon-bedrock\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76973685/problems-with-sage-installation-on-macos) appears to be about [something else](https://roots.io/bedrock/).  Not sure if we need a tag for that.  [A search for 
 \[wordpress\] bedrock](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwordpress%5D+bedrock) suggests that there _are_ a bunch of questions about it...okay, I retagged that and added a handful of others to [tag:wordpress-bedrock] (there are still more to add, if anyone's really bored).

Comment: ...and since I'm here anyway, might as well... merged [bedrock] into [amazon-bedrock] (no synonym created because of the ambiguity).

Comment: @RyanM thank you